# Benefits of using ASP.NET MVC Controller Injection?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

What are Benefits of using ASP.NET MVC Controller Injection (IoC) ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I did a video on this if it helps:
http://www.asp.net/learn/mvc-videos/video-366.aspx

The idea with IoC is that you have no dependencies declared in your controller - only interfaces. This allows for high re-use.

Think in terms of membership - you might have an AccountController you really like and want to carry around with you. Normally you might use Linq to Sql, but on this new project you want to use SubSonic or NHib. If you use IoC there is *no* code you need to change in your AccountController - you only need to implement your new interface.

Answer (score 1):

Pretty much the same general advantages one gets from dependency injection applied to the case of MVC controllers.

Answer (score 0):

As in any other place where IoC is used, injecting dependencies usually services by the Controller's constructor will give you the ability to switch between different implementations of the same interface injected. That is not very common scenario though. For me the best benefit that this gives you is to Unit Test your controllers by using Mocking framework. In that way you can isolate in your test the dependency from the services from what actually the controller is doing.